# Is there any way to pass an anonymous array as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

I'd like to be able to declare an array as a function argument in C++, as shown in the example code below (which doesn't compile).  Is there any way to do this (other than declaring the array separately beforehand)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void PrintArray(int arrayLen, const int * array)
{
   for (int i=0; i<arrayLen; i++) printf("%i -> %i\n", i, array[i]);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   PrintArray(5, {5,6,7,8,9} );  // doesn't compile
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're using older C++ variants (pre-C++0x), then this is not allowed. The "anonymous array" you refer to is actually an *initializer list*. Now that C++11 is out, this can be done with the built-in `initializer_list` type. You theoretically can also use it as a C-style initializer list by using `extern C`, *if your compiler parses them as C99 or later*.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    const int* p;
    p = (const int[]){1, 2, 3};
}
```

Comment: GCC is actually okay with this, as long as you typecast the literal: p = (int[]){1, 2, 3}; as per Adam's answer way down below.

Comment: That's true, but just to reiterate for other readers, it is not portable c++.

Comment: this doesn't work at all. I get "cast to incomplete array type const int [] is not allowed"

Answer (score 32):

It's allowed with a typecast in C++11 and in `extern "C"` with C99:

```
void PrintArray(size_t len, const int *array)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PrintArray(5, (const int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whoa, cool! i almost want to use this, though it'll be annoying for future compatibility.

Comment: If you need non-initialized stack backup, you can even use
somefunc( (char[256]{} );
I need it for local buffers that automatically grow, but should use stackmem only before growing too large.
I am not sure if it is 100% C99.

Comment: GCC says `ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-Wpedantic]`; Clang says `compound literals are a C99-specific feature [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]` when I use `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: `extern "C"` mentioned in this answer and some others do not allow you to use C features in C++, like C99 "compound literals" (not a typecast) shown here (which is not a feature of any version of C++).  `extern "C"` is for enabling C-compatible linkage for declarations.  Compound literals just so happen to work here because this is supported as a GNU C++ extension (and maybe also an extension in some other compilers.  Also the semantics of the GNU extension are slightly different to C99 as the lifetime is reduced to the current statement rather than the whole block like in C.

Answer (score 19):

This compiles, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct arr
{
   int array[5];
};

static void PrintArray(int arrayLen, arr array)
{
   for (int i=0; i<arrayLen; i++) printf("%i -> %i\n", i, array.array[i]);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   PrintArray(5, (arr){5,6,7,8,9});
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's clever - for extra hackiness you could combine this with the fact that as the last element of a struct, arr::array doesn't have to have an explicit dimension (which would allow this to be used with any size array), and maybe make arr a template, which would allow it to be used with any type.

Comment: Agreed, this is clever. I don't think you'd want to do this, but certainly +1 for cleverness.

Comment: @Tyler, doesn't compile without an explicit dimension. You can put the array length in a template parameter though.

Comment: @Tyler: or you could just use a vector.

Comment: This compiles in what?  This is not standard, at least in C++ <= '03.

Comment: @niteria:  Ok.  Anyway, it's not standard C++ '98 or '03.  Comeau for example fails to compile it.

Comment: @rbond Why not?

Answer (score 9):

### Disclaimer: For this answer I get some downvotes, but it originates from 2009, where C++ 11 was about to be defined. For modern C++ please scroll below.

Well, try using boost...

Here is the solution using the boost::assign library and bit more C++ like programming ;)

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


namespace
{
  template<class CollectionT>
  void print(CollectionT const& coll)
  {
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out(std::cout, ", ");
    std::copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), out);
  }
}



int main()
{
  using namespace boost::assign;

  print( list_of(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) );

  return 0;
}
```

### C++ 11 and higher with the explanation of particular features

Complied with clang:
`clang++ -std=c++14 -I /usr/local/include/ main.cpp`

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>


template<typename CollectionT, typename OStream>
auto // <- auto result type deduction from C++ 14
  make_output_iterator(CollectionT const& coll, OStream& out)
{
  return std::ostream_iterator<typename CollectionT::value_type>(out, ", ");
}

// here template specialization is used, to demonstrate initializer lists from C++ 11
template<typename T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> items)
//         ^----------------------^ passed by value due to move semantics
{
  using namespace std;
  cout << "printing an initializer list: ";
  copy(items.begin(), items.end(), make_output_iterator(items, cout));
  cout << endl;
}


template<typename CollectionT>
void print(CollectionT const& items)
{
  using namespace std;
  cout << "printing another collection type: ";
  copy(items.begin(), items.end(), make_output_iterator(items, cout));
  cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
  print({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9});

  using namespace boost::assign;
  print( list_of(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9) );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Starting from C++11, you can just use `std::begin(std::initializer_list const&)` to get the pointer. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
void func(int len, const int* x)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
        std::cout << x[i] << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    func(5, std::begin({1,3,6,823,-35}));
}
```

Unlike the accepted answer, this is really Standard-compatible code.

Answer (score 5):

With C++0x you could use an `std::initializer_list` (and a foreach loop)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void print (const std::initializer_list<int>& array)
{
    for (auto x : array) // C++0x foreach loop
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    print ({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
}
```

Comment: You should probably take the list by (const-)reference. Also, you're missing the 'r' at the end of 'initializer'. :)

Comment: Changed it to const reference and added the 'r' at the end of initalizer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. In the current version of the standard (ISO C++ 1998 with ammendments from 2003), it is not possible. However, in the next version of the standard "C++0x" (which, despite its name implying that it will be released in 200x, will most likely be released in 2010), it will be possible with std::initializer_list<>.

Answer (score 3):

You can use std::initializer_list list Joe D suggests, however I am not sure you can use it if you want other parameters.  (I can't seem to find any information on that.)  However, if you declare a const reference to a vector, the initializer_list that is created with { ... } will get converted to the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void PrintArray(const char* prefix, const std::vector<int>& array)
{
    std::cout << prefix << std::endl;
    for (int i : array) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    PrintArray("test array", {5,6,7,8,9} );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable number of arguments instead of passing an array:

```
static void PrintArray(int arrayLen, ...)
{
   int this_value;
   va_list array;

   va_start(array, arrayLen);
   for (int i=0; i<arrayLen; i++) 
   {
     this_value = va_arg(array, int);
     printf("%i -> %i\n", i, this_value);
   }
   va_end(array);
}
```

I didn't compile this so I probably made a mistake or two, but hopefully it's close enough.  Look up va_start for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple clean solution to get a C-style array that no-one else has mentioned:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int N>
int
get_last( const int ( &my_array )[N] ) {
  return my_array[N-1];
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Last: " << get_last( { 1, 2, 3, 55 } );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: amazing you don't even need to pass length you Sir are a genius!

Comment: This is the best answer!  It is clean, and most importantly you do NOT have to pass in the length of the array.  This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another choice would be to use array in the TR1 library which is likely to become part of the next standard and is supported by many compilers.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using std::tr1::array;
using std::cout;
using std::copy;
using std::ostream_iterator;

template <class Container>
void PrintArray(Container &values)
{
  copy(values.begin(), values.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}

int main()
{
  array<int, 5> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  PrintArray(values);
}
```

Comment: If he wanted to create a local variable, he'd just:

    int values[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    PrintArray(values);

I think he wants to do it in a single line.

Comment: +1 because you can create an anonymous array using this: `array<int,5>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ANSI-C using good ol' [va_list](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/how-to-use-variable-argument-lists-va_list/)

Templatized C++ with a `std::vector` returned for convenience in addition

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ;

struct Point
{
  int x,y;
  Point():x(0),y(0){}
  Point( int ix, int iy ):x(ix),y(iy){}
  ~Point(){printf("%d %d - the point has been destroyed!\n",x,y);}
  void print(){printf("%d,%d\n",x,y);}
} ;

// Concrete example using a list of int
int* initFrom( int numItems, ... )
{
  int* list = new int[ numItems ] ;

  va_list listPointer;
  va_start( listPointer, numItems );

  for( int i = 0 ; i < numItems; i++ )
    list[ i ] = va_arg( listPointer, int ) ;

  return list ;
}

// templatized version.
template <typename T> vector<T> initFrom( int numItems, ... )
{
  vector<T> list ;
  list.resize( numItems ) ;

  va_list listPointer;
  va_start( listPointer, numItems );

  for( int i = 0 ; i < numItems; i++ )
    list[ i ] = va_arg( listPointer, T ) ;

  return list ;
}

int main()
{
  int* theList = initFrom( 4, 900, 2000, 1000, 100 ) ;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
    printf( "Item %d=%d\n", i, theList[i] );

  puts( "\n\n--Lots of destruction using non-ptr" ) ;
  vector<Point> thePoints = initFrom<Point>( 3, Point(3,7), Point(4,5), Point(99,99) ) ;
  puts( "Our listing:" ) ;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
    thePoints[i].print() ;

  puts( "\n\n-- Less destruction using ptr" ) ;
  // Be careful of extra copy construction. Using a vector of pointers
  // will avoid that
  vector<Point*> theNewPoints = initFrom<Point*>( 3, new Point(300,700), new Point(400,500), new Point(990,990) ) ;
  puts( "Our listing:" ) ;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
    theNewPoints[i]->print() ;

  puts( "END OF PROGRAM --" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrintArray` function is expecting a `int*`, but `const`. So you can pass a temporary `int` array created with `new`.

```
PrintArray(5, new int[5]{5,6,7,8,9});
```

Or with `std::move()` to add more sense.

```
#include <utility>
PrintArray(5, std::move(new int[5]{5,6,7,8,9}));
```

Answer (score -4):

No, and it's bad coding practice anyway. Just declare `const int* foo = {5,6,7,8,9};` before the function call. Even if this did work, it wouldn't speed up your program or compile time. The values would still need to be allocated in memory and passed through the function call.

Comment: There's nothing about using initialiser lists that is "bad coding practice", as long as you use them where appropriate.

Comment: The intent isn't to speed up compile time or run time, it's to improve encapsulation.  In particular, I have a base class whose constructor takes an array of strings, and the subclass's constructor knows what the array should be.  Without being able to pass them directly to the superclass constructor, things get a bit awkward (e.g. I have to declare the array as a static variable)

Comment: I think he said "bad coding practice" because .. well you're necessarily hard-coding here