# Is it possible to have anonymous, ad-hoc arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible to create anonymous, ad-hoc arrays in C?

For example, suppose I have a function called `processArray(int[] array)` that takes an int array as its argument, can I pass it an anonymous array in the following way:

```
int main(){
 processArray( (int[]){0, 1, 2, 3} ); //can I create this type of array?
 return 0;
}
```

Or do I have to declare the array previously (with a pointer), and then pass its pointer to processArray()? For example:

```
int main(){
 int[] myArray = {0, 1, 2, 3};
 processArray(myArray);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140630/is-there-any-way-to-pass-an-anonymous-array-as-an-argument-in-c

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of asks about C++, not C.

Comment: /agreed Michael - it's NOT a duplicate; C and C++ are *distinct* languages - and this particular case is one more that only highlight the difference!

Comment: `int[] myArray`? This is not C# and must be `int myArray[]`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With C99 and C11, you can write what you wrote, as exemplified by the following code.  These are 'compound literals', described in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) (and it is the same section in ISO/IEC 9899:1999).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void processArray(int n, int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    processArray(4, (int[]){0, 1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the answer:

```
 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Note that with a macro, you could even eliminate the extra size argument: `#define processArray(a) processArray_func(sizeof (a)/sizeof *(a), (a))` But in macro arguments, you need an extra set of parentheses around compound literals to keep the preprocessor from eating the commas...unless you use a really ugly hack with `__VA_ARGS__`. :-)

Comment: Part of why I mention this is that some people see this kind of design as the proper modern alternative to variadic functions. With variadic macros and compound literals, you can make the calling convention look exactly like a variadic function, but with a lot more structure to it (e.g. the ability to programmatically generate argument lists, some type-checking abilities, etc.)

Comment: Although you can do it with the macro (and probably varargs, but it gets messy, as you say), and it avoids writing the literal out several times, you might do better with a sentinel value at the end of the array (e.g. a negative integer).

Comment: Indeed, that's a nice approach too.

Comment: I ran into an interesting, slightly related problem last week.  `#define SNBUFF(s) (s), sizeof(s)` and then uses like: `snprintf(SNBUFF(fixed_array), "%s (%s) = %d\n", xxx, yyy, zzz);`. Looks like it should be OK; it is OK unless `snprintf()` is a macro. Then `SNBUFF()` looks like a single argument to the macro, and all hell broke loose. On Mac OS X 10.7.5, there's a macro  for `snprintf()` defined via `<stdio.h>` in the included header `security/_stdio.h` like: `#define snprintf(str, len, ...) __builtin___snprintf_chk(str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)`. The fix is to lose SNBUFF.

Comment: You can always `#undef snprintf`; that's permitted by the standard. You can also write `(snprintf)(...)` instead of `snprintf(...)` to ensure a function-like macro is not expanded. Of course if you *wanted* the security/fortify stuff, this might be undesirable...

Comment: We'll take all the security we can get — but if we were willing to do without, then the 'evade the macro' techniques would certainly work.

Comment: The compiler allows me to pass in an empty anonymous array like this:
`function((char[3]){});`. Would this allocate the right amount of memory for the function to use?

Comment: @davidanderle — It's using a compiler-specific extension (the empty initializer is non-standard C).  However, it should allocate the correct memory for the type of the compound literal (3 bytes in this case).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, it means that by doing `function((char[3]){0});` I can make it ISO C compliant, correct? This would allocate 3 bytes and set the first byte (at least) to 0. I think gcc sets everything to 0 in this case. It would be a neat trick to pass in a buffer to a function that will get discarded immediately after the function has returned

Comment: @davidanderle — Yes, using `(char[3]){0}` is a valid ISO C compound literal. It would set all the bytes to zero, the first because that's the value in the initializer, and the rest because values not explicitly initialized are zeroed.  The compound literal, as amended by the called function, would be released when it goes out of scope — when the compound statement it is in ends.  It won't vanish immediately the call returns, but you won't be able to access it unless the called function returns a pointer to it and you capture that pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edited, thanks. Also thanks for the clarification! Helped a lot