# Passing an "undeclared" array to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible (like in Javascript) to pass an array directly at the call of a function as an argument like so :

```
initLevel(&L, {
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top
   }, 4, "Level 1");
```

See below the code I use :

```
// DATA STRUCTURES
typedef enum{
    DIRT_TOP_L, DIRT_TOP, DIRT_TOP_R, DIRT_L, DIRT, DIRT_R
} tile_deco;

typedef enum{
    STOP, WALK, CLOUD, PAIN
} tile_type;

typedef struct{
    tile_type caract;
    tile_deco deco;
} tile;

typedef struct {
    char *title;
    tile *board;
    int completed;
    int xMax;
    int yMax;
} level;

// FUNCTIONS
void initLevel (level* L, tile board[], unsigned int yMax, char title[]){
    unsigned int xMax = (int)( sizeof(board) / sizeof(tile) ) / yMax ;
}

// MAIN
void main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

   tile Dirt_Top;
   Dirt_Top.caract=WALK;
   Dirt_Top.deco=DIRT_TOP;

   tile Dirt_Top_L;
   Dirt_Top_L.caract=WALK;
   Dirt_Top_L.deco=DIRT_TOP_L;        

   level L;

   initLevel(&L, {
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top,
        Dirt_Top_L, Dirt_Top, Dirt_Top
   }, 4, "Level 1");

}
```

I saw a post talking about stdarg but I don't think that it would be a good solution. Please be constructive in your answers. Thank you

EDIT : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669412/is-it-possible-to-have-anonymous-ad-hoc-arrays-in-c) is what I meant

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]! There is no `levels` name in your code.

Comment: There is a structure called "level" what I meant by 'levels' is more than one 'level'

Comment: A `struct` is not an array. A pointer is neither a `struct` nor an array. If you want to program, get used to being precise so others know what you are talking about - less friction. It still is not clear what your problem is; you **cannot** use undeclared names. That's one fundamental basic concept in C. Maybe a good book can help you more to get the whole picture, than asking particular questions.

Comment: I will try to be more precise but please don't be rude.