# Can you pass an "undeclared" array to a function in C similar to an integer?

Tags: arrays, c, function, arguments

say you have:

```
int foo(int bar)
{
   //Do something with bar here.
}
```

you can call it as:

```
foo(10);
```

and this will work fine. But with an array can you do something similar? Instead of pre-declaring the array and passing it to the function like this:

```
int foo(int bar[])
{
   //Do something with bar here.
}

arr[] = {1,2,3};

foo(arr);
```

Can you do something like this?:

```
int foo(int bar[])
{
   //Do something with bar here.
}

foo({1,2,3});
```

Comment: I believe this question has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669412/is-it-possible-to-have-anonymous-ad-hoc-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Almost.  You need to use a **compound literal**:

```
foo((int []){1,2,3});
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you very much!